# How to properly install GTK theme in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, themes

I am trying to install a theme on Ubuntu 16.04. 
Here is the [link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/06/arc-gtk-theme).

But the theme is not appearing like it should appear. Given you have seen the screenshot in the link, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsfSy.png) is how it appears on my desktop.

Where am I going wrong with it?

Do I have to install anything else for the theme to work?

Answer (score 1):

This issue was reported at [github.com/horst3180/arc-theme](https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme), [issue #476](https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme/issues/476) and has since been fixed. Install using the fixed `.deb` package for 16.04: [link](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04/all/arc-theme_1459454111.c561afa_all.deb).

Comment: Could you please link to the specific issue from https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme/issues?

Comment: @DKBose Linked to #476.